# Access controllers of multiple identical directives sharing the same parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am having trouble with an angular directive used an an attribute on a component. Basically, I want buttons to be draggable. I do it this way:

```
<body>
  <xx-button xx-draggable>
  <xx-button xx-draggable>
<body>
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jedi/oqyg52ku/10/) for implementation.

The resulting DOM is:

```
<xx-button class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope" draggable="true" hm-panstart="$draggableCtrl.ondragstart($event)" hm-panend="$draggableCtrl.ondragend($event)" hm-panmove="$draggableCtrl.ondrag($event)" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
  <button class="btn ng-binding" ng-click="$ctrl.onclick()">
    CLICK ME
  </button>
</xx-button>
```

The xx-draggable directive will modify the dom of the xx-button directive to add a couple of hammer handlers (I am using angular-hammer) to manage the drag of the button. The `xx-draggable` directive has its own controller which use `controllerAs` to explicitly name it (`$draggableCtrl`). As I understand, `controllerAs` will basically attach the controller to the scope so in the template you can refer to it. The problem is, in my case, it seems `controllerAs` is attaching both controller to the same scope resulting in only the controller of the directive applied on the second button to be accessible. So when I drag the first button (button1), the second one (button2) is effectively being dragged...

My understanding is that the component is supposed to have an isolated scope, so both should not interfer. The `controllerAs` of the second directive should attach the `$draggableCtrl` to the scope of the second button and there should not be any overlap.

Any idea what is going on ?

**Update:**

I believe the root cause of my problem is described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-):

> In general it's possible to apply more than one directive to one
>   element, but there might be limitations depending on the type of scope
>   required by the directives. The following points will help explain
>   these limitations. For simplicity only two directives are taken into
>   account, but it is also applicable for several directives:
>
> [...]
>
> isolated scope + no scope => The isolated directive will use it's own
>   created isolated scope. The other directive will use its parent's
>   scope

So in fact, xx-draggable is not associated to xx-button scope but to its parent scope, that is why the controller is overwritten. This is kind of counter-intuitive in my opinion.

So my question now is, how do I manage my directive attribute to have their own scope or at least get to deal with xx-button's directive scope, knowing that I don't control the type of scope of xx-button, I am just developing a xx-draggable directive that should be applied to any kind of widget ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I settled for a far from ideal solution, but one that actually works in a relatively 'safe' way, without making assumptions on how it is used.

In order to be able to refer to the controllers of my directive independently in the template, I create a artificial 'subScope'. In the link function, I create a randomly named scope member:

```
const subScope = '_' + Math.random() * 100000000000000000;
```

I assign the controller to that randomly generated member:

```
scope[subScope] = ctrl;
```

Then, when I modify the DOM to attach handlers, I use that random reference:

```
attr.$set('hm-panstart', subScope + '.ondragstart($event)');
attr.$set('hm-panend', subScope + '.ondragend($event)');
attr.$set('hm-panmove', subScope + '.ondrag($event)');
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jedi/oqyg52ku/14/) for the working solution.